# A problem based on Tutte's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

> Let $G$ be a simple graph, with order $\nu$ even and minimum degree $\delta <\nu/2$. Show that if number of edges ($\epsilon$) in the graph be such that   $\epsilon$ > $\delta \choose 2$ + $\nu - 2\delta-1 \choose 2$ + $\delta(\nu - \delta)$, then $G$ has a perfect matching.

I am supposed to use Tutte's Theorem here. By Tutte's Theorem, for any $S \subset V$, if the number of odd components in $G-S$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $S$, then we have a perfect matching.

So, all I need to show is that for any $S\subset V$, $o(G-S) \leq |S|$. But I am having hard time establishing this from the inequality: $\epsilon$ > $\delta \choose 2$ + $\nu - 2\delta-1 \choose 2$ + $\delta(\nu - \delta)$.

I will greatly appreciate any help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

1) Minimum knowing the minimum degree is less than a certain value seems odd. Maybe we should be using this knowledge that there is a vertex of minimum degree $\delta$.

2) Given (1), have you considered the extremely simple choice for $S$?

3) That's a lot of edges. However, I believe the theorem can be strengthened. You actually only need $\epsilon > \binom{\delta}{2} + \binom{\nu - \delta - 1}{2} + \delta$.

4) I may just be cross, but consider using the normal Latin characters $n$ and $e$, as I don't think I've ever seen this Greek notation.

I should say, if you are still having difficulties, leave a comment explaining why. However, if you manage to find your own solution, post it as answer!

Comment: I think your answer works, but so does the condition specified in the problem. Let me explain one-by-one. We count edges. By your answer, if $v_0$ is a vertex of minimum degree $\delta$, then we have $\delta$ edges between $v_0$ and its neighbours. Then $\delta \choose 2$ implies edges between those neighbours among themselves i.e neighbour vertices along with $v_0$ form a complete subgraph. $\nu - \delta -1 \choose 2$ gives edges between the rest of the vertices, so they form a complete subgraph themselves. So, we have at most two disjoint complete components. Add one more edge gives result.

Comment: $\delta < \nu / 2$ comes handy with the condition specified in the problem. We use the same technique of counting edges. But here, we end up getting one connected component from the beginning to the end unlike in your case where we got connected graph in the end by adding atleast one more vertex. We again start with $v_0$  having minimum degree $\delta$. Since, $\delta < \nu /2$, $\nu - \delta -1 \geq 0$ i.e there are atleast as many vertices left in the graph after removing $v_0$ and its neighbours. Now, we count edges as follows:

Comment: $\delta \choose 2$ gives a connected subgraph of the neighbour set of $v_0$. $\delta(\nu - \delta)$ means you connect those $\delta$ neighbours with the rest of the vertices. $\nu - 2\delta -1 \choose 2$ means that you again get a complete subgraph on those vertices which are left after removing $v_0$, its neighbours and same number of the rest of the vertices equal in number to the neighbours of $v_0$. Now, you add atleast one more edge and you have a perfect matching. Is my explanation valid?

Comment: You’re getting the right numbers, but I don’t think the reasoning is sound (or at least you should be more careful). Why do the neighbors of v_0 form a clique? It very well may be that they don’t, but then we have even fewer edges. You should argue along these lines, with inequalities. Also, supposing the hypothesis is false for v_0, what does the graph roughly look like? Try to squeeze information out of this. This reasoning with v_0 is just a first step, since it must be shown for every S.